# Make javascript work on any link

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, onclick

I would like for an effect to happen (a certain `<div id="posts">` to translate left) when clicking on any link of my page. I was wondering if there was a way to do this with javascript. The only thing I thought about was the function but to add the attribute `onclick="myFunction"` to all of my links would be so long..

Maybe there is a pre-made js function that works on any link?

I also thought about using CSS `a:active` but I don't think that would be the best idea.

Thanks for the replies! :)

Comment: Use `Document.querySelectorAll()` with `addEventListener()` to add a listener to multiple nodes.

Comment: Ok thank you for the `selectorAll` but I'm not sure to have understood what the `addEventListener` will do and how it is used? @OriDrori

Comment: `addEventListener` will add a function like you would have done using onclick="myFunctiun", but to all the selected nodes.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! I'm gonna try to work with that and let you know @OriDrori

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to look for clicks on the `<a>` element, and call a function from there:

```
$('a').click(function() {
  // code to translate div left
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery to make things work like this:-

```
$('a').click(myfunction);
function myFunction() {
    //do click event stuff here :)
}
```

If you need a pure JavaScript alternative, I'm not sure if this will work but here's something you can try:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("p"); 
for(var i=0; i<p.length; i++){ 
 p[i].onclick = function(){ 
   myFunction();
 } 
}
function myFunction() {
//do click event stuff here :)
}
```

For a better understanding, you can refer to http://jsbin.com/onaci/
I'm sorry if I misunderstood you. If so, please correct me.
Thanks